# Spring Task Scheduler with scalable system

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

Our service will schedule some tasks in the future by TaskScheduler, these tasks will store in memory so to prevent tasks was lost after restarted, I stored it in database, and reload the tasks when startup. But if I have multiple instances of service, the tasks will loaded in every instances. How to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a lock system with your database. Add a new column to store the name of the instance which has already loaded tasks.

When an instance start, it requests the database to know if any other instance has already loaded tasks (instance name are set in DB). If the column is already set, the instance does nothing (jobs are already done by another instance). Else, the instance set his own name on DB and loads tasks.

Note that for updating the instance name, you'll need optimistic locking in case several instances try to acquire a lock at the same time (see: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking)